# Setting up a Django Project on CodeAnywhere

Tags: django, ide, cloud, codeanywhere

I am trying to create a running Django project on CodeAnywhere, but i just cant seem to get it running. i am starting in a very basic manner, with the below code

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('www.bbc.co.uk')
```

is it even possible to get this to open a new tab in a webbrowser, and will it be on my local machine or within codeanywhere?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can't work. That code will run on the server, not your machine - but the server won't have an environment to open a web browser.

Try actually writing a Django project.

Comment: hey Daniel,  thanks for your answer. Do you mean writing a djano project in a desktop IDE or on the cloud? sorry just a beginner!